# Complexity for C code on ARM

Tags: c, arm, workload

I am trying to run my code on an ARM device. So far it's running and I also have a tool to measure complexity. Now I have lots of standard functions I am using to perform mathematical operations, like dividing, multiplying, adding and so an.

Is it easier (i.e. less complex) if I write those functions as e.g.

```
result = a + b;
```

or as

```
"qadd %0, %1, %4;"
```

which would be arm code for this operation if the values are in the respective registers. I am just wondering if writing everything in ARM code would really reduce the complexity.
Also, how does that behave for conditionals (like If and Else).

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you have very, very poor compiler manually you will probably do worse.

Comment: **Complexity** has a technical meaning.  Are you a non-native speaker and are concerned with compiler translation to machine code?  [**Complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) is a measure of how easy it is to understand a function and can be an indicator of code quality.  Can you be very clear on what you mean by complexity if you keep using this word?  Also, http://www.castsoftware.com/glossary/software-complexity, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx, etc...

Comment: See for instance your question [Measure complexity on ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482203/good-way-to-measure-complexity-on-arm).  [tag:time-complexity] is independent of the CPU in use.  If a loop executes N^2 times, where 'N' is a parameter, then the routine is O(c*N^2) and a complier will not fix this.  The constant 'c' might change due to the compiler, but given sufficiently big input any CPU will have issues.  I think you mean 'compiler translation efficiency' or 'compiler code generation'.  Complexity is a wrong word for the concept you seem to ask about (unclear question)?

Comment: That's **not** the same operation. You either need to learn C or ARM assembly. And that's not what complexity means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the compiler take care of it, until you discover a bottleneck.

Note that `QADD` is saturating arithmetic and has different behavior to the C code you show.